# Use filter on a a multi level object array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Say I have a list of medical objects, where I want to select all objects that have a category of "MEDICATION" and also have a "Trait", which is an array of Objects, for specifically the term "NEGATION". For example:

```
[ 
  { 
   Score: 0.9978850483894348,
   Text: 'prozac',
   Category: 'MEDICATION',
   Type: 'BRAND_NAME',
   Traits: [
    { 
      Name: "SIGN"
    },
    { 
      Name: "NEGATION"
    }
  ] 
},
{ 
  Text: "pulmonary embolism",
  Category: "MEDICAL_CONDITION",
  Type: "DX_NAME",
  Traits: [
   {
     Name: "DIAGNOSIS",
     Score: 0.9635574817657471
    } ]
```

Normally for a filter I could select all objects that are medications quite easily with:

```
Object.filter( obj => obj.Category === "MEDICATION" )
```

But how would I select all objects with Medication, and also Trait with object where Name === NEGATION?

The nested array throws me off.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use a filter but use some on the sub array

```
Object.filter(obj => obj.Traits.some(t => t.Name === 'NEGATION'));
```

```js
const values = [
  {
    Score: 0.9978850483894348,
    Text: 'prozac',
    Category: 'MEDICATION',
    Type: 'BRAND_NAME',
    Traits: [
      {
        Name: 'SIGN'
      },
      {
        Name: 'NEGATION'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Text: 'pulmonary embolism',
    Category: 'MEDICAL_CONDITION',
    Type: 'DX_NAME',
    Traits: [
      {
        Name: 'DIAGNOSIS',
        Score: 0.9635574817657471
      }
    ]
  }
].filter(obj => obj.Category === 'MEDICATION' && obj.Traits.some(t => t.Name === 'NEGATION'));

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Using `some` instead of `find` is probably more semantically correct

Comment: Changed to use some instead of find